# codeIgniter 3 redirect host domain to index

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, codeigniter-3

I am trying to redirect my domain.com to domain.com/index. I tried both via route.php and httaccess. but not working.

route.php

```
$route[''] = "front_controllers/home/home_controller/index";
$route['index'] = "front_controllers/home/home_controller/index";
```

httaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

I past i added some rules in htaccess to remove "index.php" of codeIgniter.

I want to load my homepage which is on "index" on loading of domain.com

i already removed index.php , problem is i unable to access localhost/codeIgniter it gives 404 error

localhost/codeIgniter/index working fine as shown in route.php

Comment: Did you add your base url in config.php?

Comment: @SaiDeepak yes its http://localhost/codeIgniter/

Comment: @SaiDeepak yes, $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeIgniter/';

Comment: Just Try Renaming the controller file -> First letter to capital letter. Since nowadays Code igniter does that.

Comment: @SaiDeepak no, not working

Comment: Change `$route[''] = "front_controllers/home/home_controller/index";` to `$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';`. Actually, change `'welcome'` to `'front_controllers/home/home_controller/index'`.

Comment: @tpojka no luck already tried

Comment: Except the luck it needs to stay as default controller, not rerouted empty string.

Comment: @tpojka i mean i already tried in realty, the part is not in the question, i also tried empty string both are not working

Comment: Several things need to be changed. `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/'` with scheme at the beginning to let PHP know it is URL.